# How to get started with Desktop Software Architecture?

Tags: architecture, desktop

I apologise if this is a re-ask, I have had a rummage through previous questions but haven't found much that is relevant as far as I can tell apart from PoEAA but I think this may not quite what I am after.

Is a book available that deals with architectural best practices for desktop applications?

I have reached a stage where I am comfortable with a few similar programming languages such as Java and C#. However, as I'm sure you aware the classical learn language X books rarely make it into architectural issues. I have had a look at design patterns with the Head First book but now I feel I need to move on to topics such as inter class messaging (for instance is an event based system better than a method calling system?) and reliable network code.

I suppose that most people would learn this through work place experience but I am a lowly hobby programmer so this isn't an option at the moment.

Thank you for any help

John

Comment: Are you hoping to learn this with a Java or C# focus, or do you have a different language altogether in mind? Most of this is idiomatic for particular languages, and if you manage to find a language agnostic book, it will be extremely abstract and probably not very useful to you at this point. Beyond learning object-oriented programming, it's difficult to advise you any further with how vague your question is.

Comment: A .NET focus would be fine. C# and .NET is my main language/framework. Something akin to Jason Gregorys Game Engine Architecture but less game-centric.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to start with [Enterprise Patterns and practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default) books from Microsoft. they are really well written and provide good guidance for development. Also, if you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/bb969054#desktop_apps), you will see the latest trends and options in desktop development in .NET. It talks about smart clients and Prism architecture et al.

Give it a try.